# How to query Objects, where all conditions matched at teh same time

Tags: apex, soql

I have to write a query where all conditions should match at the same time.

`Account` has 3 custom fields: `Country__c`, `State__c`, and `Customer__c` (look up to `Customer_Account__c` object).

The `Customer_Account__c` object also has a 2 custom fields (`Country__c` and `State__c`).

Whenever I create an `Account` record, it will first check if any `Customer_Account__c` record exists in our database based on country and state. If yes, then map that record (`Customer_Account__c`) to `Account__c.Customer__c` . If not, create a new one.

I can deal with mapping `Customer_Account__c` to `Account`. But I am having difficulty with how to query `Customer_Account__c` record with matching `Account` field values.

**Example:**

If an `Account` has `Country__c = 'Australia'` and `State__c = 'Brisbane'`, then it will query `Customer_Account__c` records where `Country__c = 'Australia'` and `State__c = 'Brisbane'`.

Both conditions should match together. And of course we are bulkifying the trigger.

Answer (score 3):

You sort of have two questions, how to match multiple criteria and how to match against a collection.

The first is quite straightforward, use the `AND` clause:

```
SELECT Id FROM Customer_Account__c
WHERE Country__c = 'Australia'
AND State__c = 'Brisbane'
```

The second is also fairly simple. Use the `IN` clause. I would recommend using a `Set` and also make sure it does not contain `null` so as to avoid a `TableScan`. You would also get the aforementioned `TableScan` if the `Set` is empty, so don't run the query in that case.

```
Set<String> countries = new Set<String>();
Set<String> states = new Set<String>();
for (Account account : accounts)
{
    if (account.Country__c != null) countries.add(account.Country__c);
    if (account.State__c != null) states.add(account.State__c);
}
if (countries.isEmpty() || states.isEmpty() return new List<Account>();
return [
    SELECT Id FROM Customer_Account__c
    WHERE Country__c IN :countries
    AND State__c IN :states
]
```